# combining data from two tables when no data overlaps

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

This is table1:

```
customer_name|customer_id|customer_phone|customer_birthday|(10 more columns that don't match with table2)
```

This is table2:

```
customer_name|customer_id|customer_phone|customer_status|(141 columns)
```

table1.customer_id is numeric
table2.customer_id is alphanumeric

table2 was imported from an old database and contains legacy customer data

How do I get data from both tables while only specifying the columns I want from each table.
The two tables have no overlapping data.

Please help me with this. I am not sure how to resolve it

Using SQL Server 2019

Comment: `...|customer_status|(141 columns)`A table with 141 columns for details on a customer?  Well, that seems like a design flaw, if I am honest. Also, I don't understand your question, what do you mean you want the data from both, but they don't "overlap"? Do you mean that there is not relationship? If they aren't related, why do you want them in the same dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply combine data from the both tables using `UNION`:

```
select customer_name, cast(customer_id as varchar), customer_phone, customer_birthday, null customer_status from table1
union all -- no need to do a useless distinct
select customer_name, customer_id, customer_phone, null as customer_birthday, customer_status from table2
```

Answer (score -1):

As long as you have same column names, you can make a list of columns and use UNION like below:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM t1
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM t2;
```